# apache2 segmentation fault on https requests

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, openssl, opensuse, mod-ssl

I am trying to configure an old OpenSuse server with https.

The http virtualhost seems to work fine, however when I try to load the https url from my browser I get a:

```
This site can’t be reached
xxxxxxxx.it unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I have also tried to test the configuration (I am not sure if it is really ok...):

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = EssentialSSL Wildcard, CN = *.xxxxxxx.it
verify return:1
139645938849448:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.xxxxxx.it
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=EssentialSSL Wildcard/CN=*.xxxxxxx.it
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5206 bytes and written 198 bytes
openssl: symbol lookup error: openssl: undefined symbol: SSL_cache_hit
```

I have tried to take a look at the apache error log and I get this every time I try to load the https url I read a:

```
[Wed May 30 17:54:42 2018] [notice] child pid XXXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I have installed gdb and tried to debug the httpd process (I am not sure what the output really means):

```
gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.2-3.3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) attach 18063
Attaching to process 18063
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork...Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=e88f8ce4d6cd1f4529e5f57298c5dd6f95ce052a"
(no debugging symbols found)...done.

[...and so on for a lot of symbols...]

Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xmlwriter.so...Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xmlwriter.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=c29f816adba0fed5b95fb8dae0971d4481f19d5b"
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xmlwriter.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/zlib.so...Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/zlib.so
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=d7665379355708961234d0a12ba42af7e8670a52"
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/php5/extensions/zlib.so
0x00007f58c7b3ecf3 in __select_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007f58c7b3ecf3 in __select_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f58c8022765 in apr_sleep () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f58c88f49a9 in ap_wait_or_timeout ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007f58c88ff6c1 in ap_mpm_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f58c88d69be in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Server info:

```
openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11.4
CODENAME = Celadon
```

Apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Linux/SUSE)
Server built:   2012-02-14 02:29:38.000000000 +0000
```

OpenSSL:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010)
```

Comment: Have you added the Intermediate certificate from the CA?

Comment: Yes, I made a chain of all the intermediate ca files (all but the root ca)